# Recent Comments from Specific Category Widget

Tags: widgets, comments, sidebar

I've been trying to create a sidebar widget to display recent comments from specific category. I'm having difficulties in determining how Wordpress knows from which categories the comments are.

I have checked [the codex on `get_comments` function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments) but it doesn't seem to allow fetching from specific categories. I've found [some hints from Kovshenin's blog](http://kovshenin.com/2009/recent-comments-by-category-slug/), but can't seem to make it work properly, because my try either shows all comments (disregarding the categories) or doesn't show it at all.

I'm basing the widget from `Widget_Recent_Comments` (found from `wp-includes/default-widgets.php`). Here is what I have so far. I believe the output is controlled around this area:

```
    $output = '';
    $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', empty( $instance['title'] ) ? __( 'Recent Comments' ) : $instance['title'], $instance, $this->id_base );

    if ( empty( $instance['number'] ) || ! $number = absint( $instance['number'] ) )
        $number = 5;

    $category_name = empty( $instance['category_name'] ) ? '' : $instance['category_name'];

    $comments = get_comments( apply_filters( 'widget_comments_args', array( 'number' => $number, 'status' => 'approve', 'post_status' => 'publish' ) ) );
    $output .= $before_widget;
    if ( $title )
        $output .= $before_title . $title . $after_title;

    $output .= '<ul id="recentcomments">';
    if ( $comments ) {
        foreach ( (array) $comments as $comment) {
            $output .=  '<li class="recentcomments">' . /* translators: comments widget: 1: comment author, 2: post link */ sprintf(_x('%1$s on %2$s', 'widgets'), get_comment_author_link(), '<a href="' . esc_url( get_comment_link($comment->comment_ID) ) . '">' . get_the_title($comment->comment_post_ID) . '</a>') . '</li>';
        }
    }
    $output .= '</ul>';
    $output .= $after_widget;

    echo $output;
```

And here is the full codes: http://pastebin.com/VH666jty

Basically my widgets is similar to the default Recent Comments widget. Only that it has an optional `Display comments only from category/categories: ...`, where user could input by themselves.

Leaving it blank will display comments from all category, while putting some category slug, separated by comma (e.g.: `mycategory,othercategory`) will display comments only from those selected categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get your answer from *Kovshenin* blog

Replace whole `if ( $comments )` with this

```
if ( $comments ) {
    foreach ( (array) $comments as $comment) {
    $comm_post_id = $comment->comment_post_ID;
    if ( $category_name ) {
        if (!in_category( "{$category_name}", $comm_post_id )) {
            continue;
        }
    }
    $output .=  '<li class="recentcomments">' . /* translators: comments widget: 1: comment author, 2: post link */ sprintf(_x('%1$s on %2$s', 'widgets'), get_comment_author_link(), '<a href="' . esc_url( get_comment_link($comment->comment_ID) ) . '">' . get_the_title($comment->comment_post_ID) . '</a>') . '</li>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Both answers seem to work, but I guess I'd choose this as it's easier for me. Thanks a lot, @MridulAggarwal and @Dipa! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `comments_clauses` hook to customize the comment query

Replace the "join" part with

```
INNER JOIN $wpdb->posts ON($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->comments.comment_post_ID)
INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON($wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id)
INNER JOIN $wpdb->terms ON($wpdb->terms.term_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id)
```

In the "where" part append the clause based on the user input for eg. `AND $wpdb->terms.slug = 'uncategorized'`

Make an `add_filter` call just before the `get_comments` function & use the `remove_filter` call immediately afterwards so as to not modify any other queries on the page

Comment: I'm sorry, but where is `comments_clauses` located?

Comment: @deathlock Even Notepad++ has a cross file search implemented.

Comment: @kaiser yes, I'm sorry! :s I only tried Google when I commented, when I realized I should've search within my files. :s